# Warum wurde/wird empfohlen, einige Farbadjektive nicht zu beugen?

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending

Wie [in dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/adjectives-that-dont-require-adjective-endings/) festgestellt, wird z. B. vom Duden (z. B. [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tuerkis) und [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/orange)) oder Bastian Sick ([hier](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-sind-rosane-t-shirts-und-lilane-leggings-erlaubt-a-292846.html)) empfohlen, diverse eingedeutschte Farbadjektive nicht zu beugen, und stattdessen Folgendes zu schreiben bzw. sprechen:

> Ein rosa Kleid.
>   Eine pink Schleife.
>   Ein türkis Eimer.

Während ich in einigen Fällen wie *rosa* sehe, warum eine normale Beugung nicht ohne Weiteres problemlos möglich ist (siehe einmal mehr [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/adjectives-that-dont-require-adjective-endings/9394#9394)), fällt mir nichts ein, was dagegenspricht, z. B. *türkis* oder *pink* ganz normal wie z. B. *fies* oder *flink* zu beugen. Mal ganz zu schweigen davon, dass das Unterlassen der Beugung sich zumindest in meinen Ohren ziemlich falsch anhört.

**Was ist der Grund für diese Regel?**

Es geht mir wohlgemerkt weder darum, welche Variante besser, schöner, richtiger, weiter verbreitet oder Standardsprache ist, noch darum, ob die zitierten Referenzen irgendeine Autorität diesbezüglich haben, sondern nur darum, wie überhaupt jemand auf die Idee kommen konnte, z. B. *pink* nicht zu beugen.

Comment: Also wenn ich den Dudenlinks folge, erhalte ich keine Empfehlung gegen flektierte Farbattribute, sondern dafür. Bastian Sick ist normalerweise keine Referenz, aber in diesem Artikel zitiert er selber nur den Duden. Scheinbar (was laut Bastian Sick impliziert, dass es tatsächlich nicht so sei, was natürlich Humbug ist) hat der Duden vor nicht allzu langer Zeit seine Meinung geändert.

Comment: @Toscho: *Empfehlen* im Sinne von *zur bevorzugten Variante erklären,* nicht notwendigerweise im Sinne von *ausschließlich erlauben.* Es gibt aber genügend Quellen (z. B. Sick), die nicht zu beugen als ausschließlich standardsprachlich richtig betrachten – Sick habe ich nur gewählt, weil er die ausführlichste verlinkbare Darstellung bietet, nicht weil ich ihm irgendwelche Autorität zuschreibe. So oder so geht es mir nicht darum, was man nun tun sollte, sondern nur darum, was überhaupt dafür spricht.

Comment: OK, dann nimm Sick heraus. Die Dudenlinks zählen alle drei Varianten auf mit Komma getrennt auf, wobei die gebeugte Variante am Schluss steht. Siehst du das als Bevorzugung an?

Comment: @Toscho: Ja, wenn auch nur als leichte. Wieso sollte ich Sick herausnehmen? Es ist immerhin die ausführlichste Abhandlung zu dem Thema.

Comment: Tja, in "Flexion" von Thieroff und Vogel (2012) steht dazu nur: "Während es als standardsprachlich nicht korrekt gilt, diese zu flektieren, kommen im Gesprochenen durchaus flektierte Formen vor" Leider aber ohne Erwähnung, wo die Standardsprache das her hat. Wenn ich noch irgendeine brauchbarere Quelle finde, mach ich vielleicht doch noch eine Antwort draus.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Weil du im Text vom „empfehlen“ sprichst, Sicks Darstellung aber nicht als „Empfehlung“ ansiehst. Oder änder es lediglich, sodass man erkennt, dass du Sick lediglich als ausführliche Darstellung des Themas zitierst.

Comment: @Toscho: Wo habe ich geschrieben, dass ich es nicht als Empfehlung ansehe?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft „Es gibt aber genügend Quellen (z. B. Sick), die nicht zu beugen als ausschließlich standardsprachlich richtig betrachten[…]“

Comment: @Toscho: … und also insbesondere empfehlen.

Comment: Meine Grossmutter spricht in: „Der Ball ist orange.“, das E aus. Da sie fast 100 Jahre alt ist, spekuliere ich, dass sich das Wort fuer aeltere Sprecher noch als „Substantiv anfuehlt“ und die Regel dort ihren Urpsrung hat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Schon Wikipedia merkt hierzu an:

> Viele Fremdwörter und entlehnte Farbbezeichnungen, etwa rosa, sowie Adjektive der geographischen Herkunft auf -er (z. B. Elsässer) können weder dekliniert noch gesteigert werden (unveränderliche Adjektive). [(1)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjektiv#Steigerung_.28Komparation.29)

Die Eingliederung in die deutsche Sprache geschieht recht vorsichtig. Die Deklination wird erst nachfolgend mündlich "erarbeitet". Dazu wieder Wikipedia (siehe selber Link wie oben):

> In Dialekten bzw. in der Umgangssprache werden auch sonst nicht komparierbare Wörter gesteigert oder Adverbien als Adjektive gebraucht: rosa – rosaner.

Die Akzeptanz der Deklination in die Schriftsprache erfolgt verständlicherweise erst viel später.

Die etymologische Erklärung zu *rosa* sei hier als Beispiel aus Wikipedia angegeben:

> Für die Bezeichnung des Farbtons der in Europa einheimischen Wildrosen standen im mittelhochdeutschen die Wörter rōse(n)var, rœselvar, rōsīn, rōse(n)rōt und rōsic zur Verfügung. In der zweiten Hälfte des 18. Jahrhunderts wurden die neuhochdeutschen Entsprechungen (rosenfarb, rosenfarbig, rosenrot, rosig) nicht mehr genutzt. Der lateinische Blumenname rosa (‚Rose, Edelrose‘) als Benennung der Farbe wurde ins Deutsche übernommen. Für übernommene Farbwörter typisch ist die Flexion unsicher. Zunächst wurde es nur in Zusammensetzungen wie „Rosaband“, „Rosakleid“, „Rosatuch“ verwendet. Zunehmend wird es prädikativ und in der Umgangssprache auch attributiv als Adjektiv verwendet.  [(2)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_%28Farbe%29#Etymologie)

Eine tiefgreifende wissenschaftliche Untersuchung zu *rosa*, *pink* und *rot* findet man bei [Caroline Kaufmann: Zur Semantik der Farbadjektive rosa, pink und rot](http://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/6326/1/Kaufmann_Caroline.pdf). Dort finden sich auch Überlegungen zu anderen Farbadjektiven. Grundsätzlich resultieren alle Probleme der Flexion aus den Unsicherheiten beim Eingliedern neuer Wörter in die Sprache.

Weitere **unveränderliche Adjektive** sind zum Beispiel: *super* und *extra*.

Wie aus den zur Antwort gehörenden Kommentaren hervorgeht, ist derzeit die Flexion der Farbadjektive in den regionalen Dialekten wie auch das (regional bedingt?) individuelle Empfinden zu den verschiedenen Varianten extrem unterschiedlich.

Es liegt sehr nahe, dass mit Rücksicht auf diese derzeitigen Unterschiede deshalb auf Festlegung einer Beugung für die Hochsprache vorerst verzichtet wird und sie so lange als unveränderliche Adjektive belassen werden.

---

Anmerkung (typische Mechanismen der Lehnwörter):

1. Der Verlauf der Integration aus anderen Sprachen hängt auch davon ab, wie verwandt die Quellsprache mit der eigenen Sprache ist. Integration innerhalb derselben Sprachfamilie gelingt i. d. R. besser.
2. Gelingt die grammatikalische Integration nicht auf Anhieb, besteht später kaum noch eine Chance, dass es zu Ende gebracht wird. Das wird im Falle der Farbadjektive sehr wahrscheinlich so eintreten, und sie werden immer ungebeugt bleiben.

Comment: für mich klingen übrigens *rosanes Kleid*, *pinke Schleife*, *türkiser Eimer* völlig normal, und wenn ganz oben entschieden werden würde, das kommt so in die Schriftsprache, würde ich das OK finden.

Comment: @falkb Persönlich finde ich die Deklinationen von `pink` und `türkis` auch in Ordnung, störe mich aber an `rosan`, weil das eher zu den Materialattributen passt (steinern, irden, hölzern, golden, …). Als Farbattribut würde ich `rosa` eher ohne `-n-` deklinieren: `rosaes Kleid`, `rosaer Hund`, `rosaes Haus`. Der Doppelvokal ist aber sprachuntypisch.

Comment: Also hier in unserer Ecke dominiert im Falle von Deklination *rosaner*, *rosane* und *rosanes* im Dialekt. Das ist glaube ich das Problem, dass man noch keine deutschlandweite Version verordnen kann, ohne eine Ecke vor den Kopf zu stoßen. Also lässt man's lieber bei unveränderlich.

Comment: Interessanterweise finde ich das völlig OK bei rosa und lila (*das rosa/lila Kleid*, *des rosa/lila Kleides*, *dem rosa/lila Kleid*, etc.). Bei *orange* hört es jedoch schon auf: *das orange Kleid* (mit gesprochenem "e"), *des orangen Kleides*, *dem orangen Kleid*, etc. Niemals würde ich jedoch auf *rosanen*, *lilanen* oder *orangenen* verfallen...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: als gängige Variante kenne ich auch noch *ein orangnes Kleid*, *der orangne Ball*,

Comment: @falkb Gehört hab ich das auch schon - aber wie gesagt, ich käme nie auf die Idee, das selbst so zu verwenden.

Answer (score 6):

**Deskriptive Grammatik**

Beispielhaft steht dieses [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=t%C3%BCrkis%20_NOUN_,%28t%C3%BCrkises%20_NOUN_%20%2b%20t%C3%BCrkise%20_NOUN_%20%2b%20t%C3%BCrkiser%20_NOUN_%29&year_start=1840&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,t%C3%BCrkis%20_NOUN_;,c0;.t1;,%28t%C3%BCrkises%20_NOUN_%20%2b%20t%C3%BCrkise%20_NOUN_%20%2b%20t%C3%BCrkiser%20_NOUN_%29;,c0): Seit Ende des zwanzigsten Jahrhunderts wird `türkis` eher gebeugt als nicht. Dies trifft aber auf viele ähnliche Farbattribute nicht oder nicht unbedingt zu: [siehe diese ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pink%20_NOUN_,pinke%20_NOUN_&year_start=1840&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,pink%20_NOUN_;,c0;.t1;,pinke%20_NOUN_;,c0). (Man beachte, dass Google ngram einen Textkorpus durchstöbert. Die gesprochene Sprache wird nicht erfasst.)

Es lässt sich also keine derartige deskriptive Regel feststellen, geschweige denn begründen.

**Präskriptive Grammatik**

Seit Aufkommen dieser Farbattribute wurden die beugbaren Alternativen `*-farben` und `*-farbig` propagiert. Ein Großteil der Bevölkerung erwartet also diese Konstruktionen und empfindet gebeugte Farbattribute als Normverletzung und teilweise verwirrend oder sogar sinnentstellend (`orange` zu `das orangene Kleid` zu beugen, würde in der Tat aus der Farbe Orange das Material Orangenschalen machen. Die korrekte Beugung wäre, wenn man sie zulässt, `das orange Kleid` mit gesprochenem `-e`.).

Folgich sollt man im Sinne einer guten Kommunikation diese Alternativen verwenden.

Dem gegenüber steht aber ein wachsender Teil der Bevölkerung, der die Alternativen als gestelzt oder zumindest ineffizient empfindet und gebeugte Farbattribute verwendet oder akzeptiert.

Eine präskriptive Regel muss also die Adressatenschaft mit einbeziehen, was Bastian Sicks Regel nicht tut.

**Eigenes Empfinden**
Wenn man gewisse Farbattribute beugt, kommen grauselige Wörter raus. Die häufigsten Beispiele `rosa` und `lila` sind gerade solche. Vermutlich deshalb hat man die Alternativen bevorzugt. Manche Farbattribute machen überhaupt keine Probleme, z. B. `türkis`, und bei manchen wirken selbst die Alternativen holprig, z. B. `orange`.

Comment: Deine Antwort erklärt zwar, warum z. B. zum Suffix *-farben* greift statt zu beugen, aber nicht warum man das Adjektiv einfach ungebeugt stehen lassen sollte, insbesondere bei Fällen wie *pink.* Außerdem denke ich nicht, dass irgendjemand *orangen* als *aus Orangenschalen bestehend* versteht oder gar nutzt, und selbst wenn, wäre das wohl kaum ein relevantes Problem – wir unterscheiden ja auch nicht streng zwischen *golden* und *goldfarben.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Naja, wenn du bereit bist mir einen goldenen Knopf im Austausch für einen goldfarbenen zu geben :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Kein Problem, da *golden* sogar laut Duden *goldfarben* bedeuten kann – da die Mehrdeutigkeit eben in der Realität kein solches Problem wäre, dass man eine strikte Unterscheidung benötigen würde.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Damit hast du vollkommen recht. Deklarativ verstehe ich, dass man sie als undeklinierbar wie `super` ansieht, aber prozedural will es auch einfach nicht in meinen Kopf.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, der Grund ist schlicht und einfach, dass diese Autoritäten diese Wörter nicht als Adjektive akzeptieren, sondern als Substantive betrachten.
Wenn man denn ein Adjektiv braucht, dann solle man doch gefälligst "blahblahfarbig/en" verwenden.
Was nicht geht – und da sind sich alle einig – ist:

> Ein türkis Haus ...

Es geht also nicht um die Flexion an sich, sondern darum, dass Substantive keine Adjektivendungen erhalten können.

Comment: Es sind sich eben nicht alle einig: Siehe z. B. die Beispiele [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tuerkis) oder [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/orange).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... ich bin erschüttert. Der Rechtschreibduden verliert langsam meinen Respekt. In Deutsch werden ALLE vorangestellten Wörter die als Adjektiv fungieren, so flektiert. Auch Fremdwörter "Freshe Sendungen in der ARD Mediathek"... und sogar Unfug wie "ein gut genuges Auto"... mir kann keiner erzählen, dass irgendwer "ein türkis Kleid sagt" ohne das als falsch zu empfinden.

Comment: Zumindest bei *super, extra* und *klasse* ist es ziemlich normal, sie nicht zu flektieren. Und auch wenn ich seine Meinung nicht teile, ist der Duden damit nicht ganz alleine.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... super Beispiele. a hab' ich nicht dran gedacht.

Comment: @Emanuel: Mein volles Mitgefühl. Aber kein +, denn offenbar gehen die Gefühle auseinander. Ich finde ein **rosa Kleid** richtig und **rosanes Kleid** albern, bei türkis erlaubt mein Ohr nur **türkises Kleid** und das **pinke Kleid** soll es bitteschön heissen. Was ich aber in den Kommentaren als passend für orange lesen muss verwirrt mich total. Scheint wirklich noch in der Findung befindlich...

Comment: @userunknown... aber ich sage doch nichts anderes in der Antwort. Ich finde auch "rosa" besser aber über die Adjektve die in Vokal enden steht da nix. Mein einziges Beispiel ist "türkis". Und die Frage war nicht "Wie ist die Regel" sondern "Warum gibt es eine bestimmte Regel". Meine Theorie ist, dass die daruf basiert, dass man die Betroffenen Farben als Substantiv definiert und nix anderes steht in meiner Antwort.