# Was ist so schwierig an der Farbe Orange?

Tags: etymology

Wenn man die adjektivische Bezeichnungen für die Farbe *Orange* liest, findet man ganz verschiedene Bezeichnungen, die alle im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/orange) gelistet sind:

> - der **orange** Koffer.
> - der **orangene** Koffer.
> - der **orangenfarbene** Koffer.
> - der **orangenfarbige** Koffer.
> - der **orangefarbene** Koffer.
> - der **orangefarbige** Koffer.

Wie erklärt sich dieses Phänomen, das wir bei anderen Farben nicht so ausgeprägt sehen? Welche Variante ist die empfohlene?

Comment: Man beachte diesbezüglich auch die Farbe "beige", die ähnliche, aber nicht ganz so ausgeprägte Probleme macht.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen: »Das Werkzeug ist im orange Koffer.«, was einige Präskriptivisten immer noch propagieren. (Siehe auch [diese Frage von mir](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9395/2594).)

Comment: Dass das Wort recht neu ist, ist bekannt, oder?

Comment: @CarstenS: die Beugung oder Nicht-Beugung interessiert mich zwar nicht, aber die Antwort dort  gibt mir auch eine hinreichende Antwort auf meine Frage, danke.

Comment: Ich erinnere mich nicht, ob ich das letztes Mal auch schon geschrieben habe, aber das hier ist vielleicht unterhaltsam, auch wenn es die Frage nicht beantwortet: http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley/2014/09/lexicon_valley_the_etymology_and_history_of_the_word_orange_with_lexicographer.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich vermute, es hat damit zu tun, dass diese Farbbezeichnungen (orange, beige, rosa, mauve, cyan, magenta etc) nicht aus dem Deutschen kommen und nicht vollständig "eingedeutscht" sind, und da ist es kompliziert mit der Anwendung deutscher Grammatikregeln. Ähnliche Probleme gibt es ja auch mit aus dem Englischen übernommenen "technischen" Begriffen z.B. "mailen", "googeln" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Der Grund dürfte sein, dass bei einer Verwendung von "orange" als Adjektiv viele Formen beim Hören nicht vom Substantiv "Orange" zu unterscheiden sind.

Z.B. hört man bei "Sie trägt die orange Hose" erst einmal "Sie trägt die Orange", erst nach "Hose" löst es sich auf. Ähnlich bei Akkusativ Singular oder Dativ Plural "den orangen", was sich genauso anhört wie "den Orangen".

Zwar ergibt sich aus dem Kontext, was gemeint ist. Trotzdem wird kann man als Hörer leicht erst einmal stutzig werden. Das ist, wie ich vermute, der Grund, dass "orange" als Adjektiv vermieden wird.

Comment: Ich bin ein bisschen skeptisch, ob das die Erklärung sein kann, weil *lila* oder *rosa* auch ohne Doppeldeutigkeit ganz ähnliche Wortbildungen haben.

Comment: Bei *lila* und *rosa* ist der Grund offenbar ein anderer, nämlich dass ein deutsches Adjektiv normalerweise nicht auf -a enden kann. Allerdings werden *lila* und *rosa* als unflektierte Adjektive verwendet, nur in der Umgangssprache kann man manchmal anderes hören ("Das rosane T-Shirt")

Comment: *Orange* kommt im Satz vor *Hose*, okay. Aber dass man den Satz zunächst bis *orange* hört, das als *Orange* interpretiert und den Satz so verarbeitet und die Hose erst hinterher hinzufügt und den Satz neu verarbeitet, das glaube ich nicht. Man kann die Lautfolge [oˈʁɑ̃ːʒə] (oder [oˈʁaŋʒə]) sowohl als Nomen als auch als Adjektiv im Kopf haben, ohne zunächst an das Nomen zu denken. Mit der Farbe habe ich definitiv häufiger zu tun. Man könnte [prototypensemantisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototypensemantik) untersuchen, ob Probanden diese Lautfolge eher als Frucht oder als Farbe sehen.