# Kann man rot steigern?

Tags: adjective

Von zwei Deutschlehrern wurde mir - bzw. meinem Kind - gesagt, dass man Farben steigern kann. Explizites Beispiel der Lehrer: „Unsere Schule ist gelb, aber die Blume ist gelber.“ Ich habe das natürlich sofort verneint, jedoch habe ich im Duden nachgeschaut und gesehen, dass dort die Steigerungsformen für rot und dergleichen vorhanden sind. Kann jemand sagen, warum das dort erfasst steht bzw. seit wann?

Comment: An alle: Bitte diskutiert nicht in den Kommentaren, was "sinnvoller" oder "folgerichtiger" ist. Wir versuchen hier nicht, über die Regeln der deutschen Sprache zu _entscheiden_, wir versuchen, die tatsächlich existierenden Regeln zu _beschreiben_. Die Frage mit der Steigerung der Farbadjektive ist berühmt-berüchtigt für Dissens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bei der Steigerungsfähigkeit von Adjektiven muss man zwischen zwei Fragen unterscheiden:

1. Ist es in der Sprache üblich, typisch, "erlaubt"?
2. Ergibt es Sinn? Ist es logisch?

Mitunter werden diese beiden Fragen vermischt. Würde man etwa argumentieren, dass es das Wort "röter" in der deutschen Sprache nicht geben kann, weil es unlogisch sei, dann würde man diese beiden Ebenen vermischen.

Die Regeln der Sprache sind aber nicht an Logik gebunden. Eine Aussage kann bedeutungstragend sein, selbst wenn sie unlogisch oder logisch falsch ist ("Weniger ist mehr" ist etwa ein Beispiel hierfür). Das gilt auch für die Bedeutung von Worten: Die Bedeutung eines Worts hängt von *Konventionen* ab, nicht von Logik. Würden die Sprecher:innen des Deutschen darin übereinkommen, dass das Wort *Grünkehlchen* ab morgen einen Vogel bezeichnet, der eine blaue Kehle hat, dann wäre das unlogisch. Es wäre nichtsdestotrotz die Bedeutung dieses Wortes im Deutschen.

Die Steigerung eines Farbadjektivs kann sogar eine sinnvolle Bedeutung haben; nämlich etwa dann, wenn die Farbe für etwas anderes steht. Der folgende Satz:

> Ich kann nicht verstehen, warum er auf die Kreuzung gefahren ist. Die Ampel war wirklich röter als rot.

sagt nichts über den Farbton des Ampellichts aus, sondern vielmehr, dass die Ampel schon sehr lange rot war.

Es ist im Deutschen möglich, Farbadjektive zu steigern. Es gibt aber eine Gruppe von Sprecher:innen, die die Steigerung von Farbadjektiven als "falsch" empfinden, weil es ihnen unlogisch erscheint.

Zusätzlich ist zu beachten, dass bestimmte Farbadjektive nicht gebeugt werden. Dies hat auch Auswirkungen auf ihre Steigerungsform. [Wir haben hier bereits eine Frage dazu.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9395/warum-wurde-wird-empfohlen-einige-farbadjektive-nicht-zu-beugen)

Comment: Ich hatte das Wort Hyperlativ gelesen für die nicht übliche Verwendung der Steigerung, ist das ein gebräuchlicher Terminus?

Comment: @ReneKockisch *Hyperlativ* ist ein Begriff, der an sich nicht in Grammatiken gebraucht wird (weil er nicht sehr logisch ist, und wenn, dann mit einem Augenzwinkern). Er wird manchmal für "deutsch" gesteigerte Fremdwörter, die bereits im Original ein Superlativ sind z.B *optimalst*, *minimalst*, oder für deutsche Adjektive, die nun wirklich nicht zu steigern sind [*einzigst*] sind, verwendet - und trifft auf "blauer" oder "am schwärzesten" nicht zu.

Answer (score 6):

Die mit "ursprünglich deutschen" Adjektiven bezeichneten Farben (rot, grün, blau, schwarz und weiß, braun, grau,...) kann man eigentlich schon immer steigern (was uns schon die Werbung zeigt: "*xxx wäscht weißer als weiß*").

Eher ungewöhnlich werden die aus den romanischen Sprachen übernommenen Adjektive für Mischfarben gesteigert (lila, rosa, beige, orange, türkis...). Das liegt daran, dass z.B. "rosa" seine Intensität aus den Intensitäten von "blau" und "rot" bezieht - deswegen kann es ein "blaueres" und ein "röteres" "Rosa", aber kein "rosaeres Rosa" (wie man sieht, greift wegen der fremden Endung hier auch die typische Bildungsregel für einen deutschen Komparativ nicht richtig und liefert ein ziemlich gruslig ausssehendes Wort) geben.

Was du gelernt hast, ist eine vereinfachte Regel, die man frühen Grundschülern und auch DaF-Schülern beibringt, um sie nicht zu verunsichern, denn hier handelt es sich nicht um ein Problem der deutschen Sprache (die Steigerungsformen für praktisch alle Adjektive und sogar Partizipien vorsieht, auch sog. "absolute" wie "schwanger" und "tot"), sondern um ein Semantik-/Logikproblem.

Einigt man sich darauf, dass es z.B. ein "absolutes Rot" in der Natur gar nicht gibt, kann man sich auch darauf einigen, dass zumindestens ein Komparativ notwendig ist, um Abstufungen in der Intensität auszudrücken, will man nicht auf Hilfskonstruktionen wie "intensiver rot" ausweichen. Hier nimmt die Sprache eben eine Abkürzung im Vergleich zur strengen Logik. Sprache läßt "schwarze Schimmel" und "zentrale Eckpfeiler" zu, warum sollte sie dann kein "blaueres Blau" erlauben?

Comment: An alle: Wir sollten nicht in den Kommentaren diskutieren, was "sinnvoll" ist oder nicht. Bitte schreibt eine gut begründete Antwort, wenn ihr eine andere Antwort für richtig haltet.

Answer (score 2):

Als Ergänzung zu den sehr treffenden Antworten über die Sinnhaftigkeit:

Es existieren Fälle, in denen eine Steigerungsform von rot notwendig wird, um Phrasen aus anderen Sprachen zu übersetzen, und die Konvention hier scheint zu sein, "roter" statt "röter" zu nehmen. Als Beispiel:

"Roter (bzw. röter) als rot" scheint im Chinesischen eine Beschreibung für besonders treue Parteimitglieder zu sein, und wird von da aus als "redder than red" ins Englische übersetzt; in den deutschen Medien landet sie dann als "roter als rot" ([Hier](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/chinas-neuer-starker-mann-xi-roter-als-rot-a-728624.html) zum Beispiel im Spiegel, [hier](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiOoazG28v6AhWlwAIHHQMIDm0QFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.focus.de%2Fpolitik%2Fausland%2Fstaats-und-parteichef-xi-jinping-geschickter-strippenzieher-unter-druck-so-tickt-chinas-maechtigster-mann_id_5613653.html&usg=AOvVaw3C0Emqjx0lbFc9J1u2RQsr) im Focus). Die genannten Medien haben natürlich keine finale Entscheidungshoheit über deutsche Grammatik, bieten aber vielleicht einen Anhaltspunkt.